# Can I update ANT plugin in Intellij 8?

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

I have Intellij IDEA 8 and the ANT app is old on that version, I was wondering if I can update only the ANT app on that intellij 8, If I can do, can somebody point me to how to do it please?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of IntelliJ ?

Comment: @gareth_bowles because to update to the last version meant $$ and I did not need it until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Build file properties` dialog has an option to **Use custom Ant** under the `Execution` tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder I did upgrade to the last version, but this is a great answer to try it.